# Provisioning, certificate, error from debugger

Tags: iphone, push-notification, certificate

**EDIT:** *After trying many, many things over and over again I've decided to **upgrade to  xCode 4** and problems stopped. I don't know what was wrong so unfortunately this is my advice to the rest of you who are lost with the problem I had.

PS thank you all for your suggestions :)*

Hi everyone,

I don't know why, but my app stopped compiling on my device after trying to enable push notifications. In debug mode with developer certificate it was running ok, but I was getting push notification related error in the console. After reading about this problem I realized I'll have to sign the code with Distribution certificate in order to really test the push notification. After "playing" with these things my app could not be deployed on the testing device anymore…
I am getting 2 errors over and over again:

**1. The executable was signed with invalid entitlements**

and when I solve this problem by changing the "code signing identity" to another developer certificate (admin) I get another one:

**2. A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.**

I tried all of the following:
- I logged with my team admin's pass and deleted /revoked certificates and profiles, recreated them and installed them on my computer. In keychain everything seems ok (certificates with keys) and in xCode Organiser (new profiles) also.

- I cleaned targets several times
- created Entitlements.plist with custom value "get-task-allow" unchecked
- In Entitlements.plist I put my bundle identifier
- I removed profiles from iphone device and tried again. It installs right provisioning profile
- I restarted computer/xcode, iPhone several times

Then, when I saw that I'm going crazy I've decided to try to start another application just to see if this one can be run.
Guess what… It can't. I get the same two errors as above.

I'll explain how I recreated things in developer portal step by step so that you can see If I'm missing something. Just have in mind that we are using 2 developer tools accounts (team admin (A), team member (B)). I'm saying this because I might have done something wrong while recreating certificates and profiles…

REMOVING OLD SETTINGS

1 deleted certificates (dev and distribution) and private keys from keychain.

2 removed all provisioning profiles from xCode Organiser.

3 In developer portal (as Admin) I revoked its Development certificate and then removed Distribution certificate

4 In devices I removed my iPhone device

5 I removed all Development provisioning profiles. The Distribution ones cannot be removed???

6 Then I logged into Team Member's account and revoked development Certificate

CREATING NEW CERTIFICATE; PROFILE...

1 In keychain assistant I created new CSR and uploaded it, admin approved it and I downloaded it along with WWDR intermediate certificate. Drag and dropped them into keychain - login / category -  certificates

2 I added my device name/identifier

3 In PROVISIONING/DEVELOPMENT I created new provisioning profile. I added my developer, all devices, and app ID.

4 Then from my team member account I downloaded it, double clicked it and that was it.

5 In xCode Project info I set code sign to developer certificate, and I ran and built with Device / Debug. I get build succeeded and error: *The executable was signed with invalid entitlements*

TAPPING IN THE DARK:

//I create enitlements.plist and run and I get: *Error from debugger: The program being debugged is not being run.*

//Then I add get-task-allow = false and I get the: *The executable was signed with invalid entitlements.*

//If I change it to true then I get: *Error from debugger*

//Then I add my app Id to Entitlements as a pure string. Nothing changes here :( - either

Thank you very, very much for even reading my post. 
Hope I'll solve  this before going nuts…

Best regards,
Luka

Comment: This is really not the place for rants. Hundreds of people on this forum are able to do what you want to do and do it every day, I'd advise rewording your post to be more concise and direct so someone can more easily help you.

Comment: I took the freedom to remove the first paragraph. While I share your rage over the (sometimes) weird code signing process, I still think you can solve your problem without issuing random insults. Be a real man (or woman), you'll solve it, somehow. Others have done it before.

Comment: I am really sorry for the first paragraph which was insulting. I admit, I should have chosen my words carefully. Still, I hope you understand my frustration...

Comment: I totally do. I had some "moments" with code signing just recently. Because I'm often working for clients who have their own developer accounts (but have little or no knowledge of code signing or the development process as a whole), most of the time I'm not the team leader. This constellation alone - apart from other errors - has caused me much calamity. So, as I said, I know your troubles...

Comment: I admire your calamity :) Thank you for sharing it with me. L

Answer (score 1):

For that you have import private key(.p12) of mac of your team leader then it will work.I face the same problem it works then only if you will have private of that mac from where the certificate made.Hope so that it will help.

Comment: I just exported his key and imported it into my keychain. Nothing changed :((( 
It's weird situation. Everything was created from my comp (team member) because admin gave me his login to do it all so I don't know for which part I need his private key? I remember when we did it first time (using my and his computer) we had to export his key... If I'm not mistaken it was for DISTRIBUTION certificate which I'm not using at the moment. I'm trying to run app using my DEVELOPMENT certificate.

Answer (score 0):

I just spent a few hours with this exact error, the steps i took to resolve it were:

- check that app ID has push enabled
- create a new provisioning profile
- delete all other profiles in xcode and on the device and use new profile
- ***(building and installing on device without error)***
- create entitlements.plist and add in get-task-allow, change type to boolean, set to true
- ***(now getting entitlement error)***

So after much googling i found a blog post about how images can affect this so i checked and noticed we were in the middle of changing the app icon and currently didn't have one set. So I threw in a older app icon and it just started building like magic and giving me the device token.

Comment: I added icon.png to my project and stil no change :(